# How to do a flow of work automaticlly each time after yarn?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

A project required **A dependence** which required **B**. And I want to change some code in **B**. But each time I rerun `yarn` (add new dependence), these changes all rolled back.

For example: in my *react-native* project I required `"react-navigation": "^2.0.1"`, and in `react-navigation's package.json` also required `"react-native-safe-area-view": "^0.8.0"`. I change some code in `react-native-safe-area-view/index.js` because it's hard to upgrade react-navigation.

Another example: same project I change some code in `RNCamere.m`(Objective-C) which in `node_modules/react-native-camera/ios/RN/RNCamera.m`. It's hard to upgrade `react-native-camera`.

But each time I add new dependence (`yarn add`) these changes were all rolled back. So I have to do the same thing again. And my partners also have to do the same thing again and again.

Is there any good solutions for optimizing this workflow? I really don't want to do the same work.

I think using `sed` to change these files each time after yarn is a good way, but I have to write long long script to fix it. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can use the `yarn link` command to link a local version of the dependency. See the docs: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/link/

Comment: You should never modify code in `node_modules` find an other way to achieve what you need. You can for example fork the packages you need to change into your own repo and use your version instead of the original one. Just modify what you need and keep pulling in the latest code from the original package.

Comment: @kumar_harsh   @apokryfos  thank you. But it's not fit for the first example. Project rely on A , A rely on B, so B is not in project's `package.json`, but in project's `node_modules`. In this situation I change B's code.

Comment: You can configure yarn to look for B from alternative sources. Not sure how but it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a fork of the `react-native-safe-area-view` project, in one of your repo. Then in your `package.json` add something like this in your dependencies:

```
"react-native-android-action-sheet": "git+ssh://git@url_of_your_fork/react-native-safe-area-view.git#v0.0.1",
```

Comment: Sorry, still face a problem of wrong reference: A requires old B,   and I put new B in package.json, it will download new B to /node_modules and download old B to /node_modules/A as well. So the new B never be used by A.

Answer (score 0):

My situation was: project relies on A, A relies on B, A also relies on C, and C also relies on B.

```
node_modules:
  react-native-safe-area-view@0.8.0     -> B@0.8.0
  react-navigation@2.2.0                -> A
  react-navigation-tabs@0.5.0           -> C
    node_modules:
      react-native-safe-area-view@0.7.0 -> B@0.7.0
```

My solution was:

1. fork these three projects on github
2. git revert to the tag version
3. change the code where needs to be modified
4. modify A's `package.json` to git+https://github.com/MYNAME/**C**.git/#mytag
5. modify B's `package.json` to git+https://github.com/MYNAME/**C**.git/#mytag
6. modify A's `package.json` to  git+https://github.com/MYNAME/**B**.git/#mytag
7. modify project's `package.json` to git+https://github.com/MYNAME/**A**.git/#mytag

So the problem solved. It's a hard(bad) try.

Here's the github issue detail: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5205